# How to render Image only once

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array of images:

```
[
  {
    'base64': ...
  }
  ...
]
```

And I render these images with:

```
<Image
    source={{
        uri: 'data:' + image.mime + ';base64,' + image.base64
    }}
/>
```

The problem is that it takes a lot of time to render and everytime I quit and go back to the screen, React re-renders all the images.
I've tried [FastImage](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) but it doesn't help so I'm thinking about rendering those images only once when the app starts and hiding/showing them depending on the current screen.

Comment: Base64 image will have to parsed and re-render it self every time you load the page

Answer (score 0):

Base64 takes lot of time to process, instead use image file with .jpg or .png extension.

By stock the images, I think you mean to store the Images in React-native project and render them. In this case you can use the `<Image>` tag like this,

```
<Image source={require("./ImageName.png")}/>
```

If you want to traverse one-level above from the .js file your working on, then use `./` , If you want to jump two level above, then use `../` in the `<Image>` tag.

Hope this helps. If any doubts do comment !

Comment: But I want to stock the images internally in my app :(

Comment: I edited my answer @NewBieBR check if it fits your question.